# How to fix unstable WIFI connection?

Tags: wireless

since a few days my wifi connection is unstable. for some moments it works and then it crashes.
What further question do I need to ask for the solution?
is this a general problem?

edit:
ubuntu 22.04

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3

Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7921 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter 
Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device
Kernel driver in use: mt7921e
Kernel modules: mt7921e

sudo dmesg | grep mt7921e

[    2.405415] mt7921e 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.423465] mt7921e 0000:02:00.0: ASIC revision: 79610010
[    2.530153] mt7921e 0000:02:00.0: HW/SW Version: 0x8a108a10, Build Time: 20220209150832a
[    2.793200] mt7921e 0000:02:00.0: WM Firmware Version: ____010000, Build Time: 20220209150915
[    2.826025] mt7921e 0000:02:00.0: Firmware init done
[    3.629627] mt7921e 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0

uname -r

5.15.0-58-generic
```

Comment: There may be a ton of reasons. You didn't provide any information at all.

Comment: is there a command were I can get these informations?

Comment: Wi-Fi problems may be related with hardware, neighbor APs and many other reasons. To see which hardware you are using, you can run `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`.

Comment: thanks, just refreshed my question

Comment: Now you can get a log by `sudo dmesg | grep mt7921e`

Comment: And what is the kernel version?

Comment: how to know the kernel version?

Comment: All looks good. Check logs when Wi-Fi disconnects.

Comment: Please add: `sudo dmesg | grep wlp` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.